# How do I set arguments to a custom jquery function and then call that function on scroll and pass in some arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a custom function that I want to make dynamic as much as possible because, as you can see right now, whenever it gets to the trigger point, the two lines of text both come in at same time.

I want the second line of text to wait a bit (maybe halfway through the first line of text's animation) before it starts firing up the function.

My solution is to set parameters when creating the function to pass in different values for each new instance of the function and probably put a delay or queue between them to stop them from executing at the same time.

i.e. `$(document).scroll(revealTextOnScroll(paragraph1, overlay1);`
`$(document).delay(2000).scroll(revealTextOnScroll(paragraph2, overlay2);`

Is this possible?

https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/jmQqvQ?editors=0010

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var text = $("p");
  var overlay = $(".someYellowOverlay");
  var flag = false;

  $(document).scroll(revealTextOnScroll);

  function revealTextOnScroll() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos >= 250 && flag === false) {
      flag = true;
      revealText();
    } else if (scrollPos < 250) {
      flag = false;
      $(text).css("display", "none");
      $(overlay).css("transform-origin", "left center");
    }

    function revealText() {
      $(overlay).addClass("someAnimation").delay(250).queue(function(next){
      $(this).css("transform-origin", "right center");
      next();
      }).delay(125).queue(function(next){
      $(text).css("display", "block");
      next();
      }).delay(250).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("someAnimation");
      next();
      })
    }
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define this:

```
var overlay = $(".someYellowOverlay");
```

`overlay` can hold a single element OR a collection (many elements).

By the way, you don't need to redo a lookup for element after.
`$(overlay)` is useless... You can use `overlay` directly.

Now have in mind that it may be a collection, so what you will do will apply on each of them.

That is why I took the parents instead.
I now can "cycle" through them to apply the delays I want to their children.

Here is the code, you can play with it in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qmQmwa?editors=0010).
Feel free to ask if you have questions.
;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var text = $("p");
  var overlay = $(".someYellowOverlay").parent();
  var flag = false;

  $(document).scroll(revealTextOnScroll);

  function revealTextOnScroll() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    var targetPos = $("header").offset().top;

    if (scrollPos >= 250 && flag === false) {
      flag = true;
      revealText();
    } else if (scrollPos < 250) {
      flag = false;
      text.css("display", "none");
      overlay.children().css("transform-origin", "left center");
    }

    function revealText() {

      var delayBetweenLines = 2000/overlay.length;

      for(i=0;i<overlay.length;i++){

        overlay.eq(i).children().first().addClass("someAnimation")

          .delay((i*delayBetweenLines)+250).queue(function(next){
          $(this).css("transform-origin", "right center");
          next();
        })
          .delay((i*delayBetweenLines)+125).queue(function(next){
          $(this).next().css("display", "block");
          next();
        })
          .delay((i*delayBetweenLines)+250).queue(function(next){
          $(this).removeClass("someAnimation");
          next();
        })

      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: this could work but i was looking for something more like https://agence-belle-epoque.fr/en as you scroll down to the next section the second line of text only comes in after a few seconds the first line's animation commences and not both at the same time, would this be possible with my current code?

Comment: I had a little fun with timings... But here it is on this second [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/QvJMGK?editors=0010).

Comment: I managed to figure out a part of it https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/jmQqvQ?editors=0110 the only problem left is why it doesn't reset when I scroll up past < 250, i don't believe this effect can be achieved using your method as the loop finishes running the first child's function before doing anything with the second child and that's not what i wanted, check out my pen i figured it out but for some reason it doesn't reset anymore

Comment: mm... I not able to explain why exactly... But this is a queuing problem. I added `clearQueue()` in [**your CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VbVMLL?editors=0010) and it works.